# Refactor recursive modifications of tree

Tags: java, recursion, refactoring, tree-traversal

How can I refactor the following code:

```
class ModifyTree{
    public void doActionsOnTree(Tree tree) {
        rAction1(tree.getRoot());
        rAction2(tree.getRoot());
    }

    private void action1(Node node) {
        // do something with node;
    }

    private void action2 (Node node) {
        // do something with node
    }

    private void rAction1(Node node) {
        action1(node);
        for(Node nodeIterator : node.getChildren())
            rAction1(nodeIterator);
    }

    private void rAction2(Node node) {
        action2(node);
        for(Node nodeIterator : node.getChildren())
            rAction2(nodeIterator);
    }
}
```

Methods `rAction1()` and `rAction2()` looks very similarly. Is there a way to don't repeat the code in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Visitior pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
interface NodeHandler {
    public void handleNode(Node node);
}

class ModifyTree{
    private void handleNodeAndChildren(NodeHandler nodeHandler, Node node) {
        nodeHandler.handleNode(node);
        for(Node child : node.getChildren()) 
            handleNodeAndChildren(nodeHandler, child);
        }
    }

    public void doActionsOnTree(Tree tree) {
        handleNodeAndChildren(new NodeHandler() { public void handlNode(Node n) {/* code for raction1 goes here*/}}, tree.getRoot());
        handleNodeAndChildren(new NodeHandler() { public void handlNode(Node n) {/* code for raction2 goes here*/}}, tree.getRoot());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn `action1` and `action2` into objects:

```
interface Action {
    void doAction(Node node);
}
Action action1 = new Action() {
    @Override
    public void doAction(Node node) {
        // what used to be the body of action1()
    }
}
Action action2 = new Action() {
    @Override
    public void doAction(Node node) {
        // what used to be the body of action2()
    }
}
```

Then you can write a single recursive method:

```
private void rAction(Action action, Node node) {
    action.doAction(node);
    for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
        rAction(action, child);
    }
}
```

For a more general version of this idea, take a look at the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: About the same answer as me, but you correctly said that this is the visitor pattern :)

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld - Indeed, about the same answer. You were quicker about it, though, so +1 to you. :) I think the command pattern is also quite appropriate for this.